# Nested UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animate:completion not delaying

Tags: objective-c, uikit, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

```
// Animate moving the cards into position
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations: ^{ card.frame = cardFrame; }
                     completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                   delay:3.0
                                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                              animations: ^ { card.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgBack.png"]; }
                                              completion:NULL];
             }
                     }];
```

> for some reason the second delay just won't delay. and the animation continues instantly any help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having actually has nothing to do with nesting. `UIImageView` simply cannot animate the `setImage:` property, and hence the code is executed as soon as it is reached.

If you are OK with simply delaying setting the image property, then go ahead and use:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    card.image = newImage;
});
```

If you are looking to animate the image changing, you might wanna look into `CATransition`, and apply a transition effect to images changing within the image view.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think i'm going to look into CATransition as i would like to animate the change as it would look a bit more user friendly.